# How do I remove a specific extension from files recursively using a bash script

Tags: bash, filenames

I'm trying to find a bash script that will recursively look for files with a .bx extension, and remove this extension.  The filenames are in no particular format (some are hidden files with "." prefix, some have spaces in the name, etc.), and not all files have this extension.

I'm not sure how to find each file with the .bx extension (in and below my cwd) and remove it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Forgot to mention, running this on OS X.  tylerl's solution works great.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.bx' -type f | while read NAME ; do mv "${NAME}" "${NAME%.bx}" ; done
```

Comment: `"${NAME}" "${NAME%.bx}"` is better. File names might contain spaces!

Comment: This is perfect, thanks.  After looking around, I believe that you can also do it using regex in find, i.e.

find . -type f -regex '.*\.bx$' | while read i; do mv "$i" "${i%%.bx}"; done

Answer (score 2):

```
find -name "*.bx" -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/\.bx//'
```

Comment: Does not work for me (no effect). The version of `rename` shipped on Linux (centos 5.5) does not support regular expressions. See Raghuram's answer for a working solution.

Comment: Seems to depend of the version then - man rename gives me "perl v5.10.1" (on Ubuntu 10.04.1)

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned I'm on OS X, which unfortunately doesn't ship with rename.  Your solution looks good for linux users.

Answer (score 2):

Bash 4+

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s dotglob

for file in **/*.bx
do
  mv "$file" "${file%.bx}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in the folder from where you want to do this

```
find . -name "*.bx" -print0 | xargs -0 rename .bx ""
```

Comment: syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "."
xargs: rename: exited with status 255; aborting

Answer (score 1):

`for blah in *.bx ; do mv ${blah} ${blah%%.bx}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version which does the following:

1. Finds out files based on `$old_ext` variable (right now set to `.bx`) in and below `cwd`, stores them in `$files`
2. Replaces those files' extension to nothing (or something new depending on `$new_ext` variable, currently set to `.xyz`)

The script uses `dirname` and `basename` to find out file-path and file-name respectively.

```
#!/bin/bash

old_ext=".bx"
new_ext=".xyz"

files=$(find ./ -name "*${old_ext}")

for file in $files
do
    file_name=$(basename $file $old_ext)
    file_path=$(dirname $file)
    new_file=${file_path}/${file_name}${new_ext}

    #echo "$file --> $new_file"
    mv "$file"    "$new_file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Extra:  How to remove any extension from filenames

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f | sed 's/.\///g'| grep -E [.] | while read file; do mv $file ${file%.*}; done
```

will cut starting from last dot, i.e.   pet.cat.dog  ---> pet.cat

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f | sed 's/.\///g'| grep -E [.] | while read file; do mv $file ${file%%.*}; done
```

will cut starting from first dot, i.e. pet.cat.dog ---> pet

"-maxdepth 1" limits operation to current directory, "-type f" is used to select files only. Sed & grep combination is used to pick only filenames with dot.  Number of percent signs in "mv" command will define actual cut point.

Comment: On Mac OS X you apparently need to specify the starting directory explicitly: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sed 's/.\///g'| grep -E [.] | while read file; do mv $file ${file%.*}; done`  (note the `.` after `find`).